# Can't display private posts

Tags: wordpress

I use the code bellow, works great for published posts, but I can't make it to display private posts. Why?

```
$myquery['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'protocols',
        'terms' => $termsa,
        'field' => 'slug',
    )

);
$args = array_merge(
    $myquery, 
    array(
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 
        'posts_per_page' => 7,
        'post_status'     => 'any'

    )
);
query_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13484/how-to-get-all-posts-with-any-post-status) on the WordPress stack exchange, `any` may not work as a value for `post_status`.  Does using an array as suggested there work?